# I'm getting undefined when trying to console log a simple object using a forEach function

Tags: javascript

I know this is a noobie question, but I just can't figure out why I'm gettgin undefined when I try to console log the property of an object from my database when I'm using the following forEach function.

```
  readLocations = () => {
    console.log("readlocations called")
    let locations = 
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/locations/");
    locations.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((thing) => {
        console.log("thingy object", thing)
        console.log("thingy latitude", thing.latitude)
      })
    });  
  }
```

The first console.log logs the following

```
thingy Object {
  "created_at": 1574980834124,
  "latitude": 52.4673777,
  "longitude": 13.4327486,
}
thingy Object {
  "created_at": 1575026634915,
  "latitude": 52.5169399,
  "longitude": 13.4175105,
}
thingy Object {
  "created_at": 1575043262077,
  "latitude": 52.5177105,
  "longitude": 13.4153796,
}
thingy Object {
  "created_at": 1575115938922,
  "latitude": 52.5097333,
  "longitude": 13.2829992,
}
```

However, the second log returns **undefined**

```
thingy latitude undefined
thingy latitude undefined
thingy latitude undefined
thingy latitude undefined
thingy latitude undefined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like the `thing` is populated asynchronously, after you log it

Comment: Generally, logging an object won't insert the double-quotes around the key names. It sounds like your DB call doesn't return a simple object. I suggest checking the API to determine if you need to so something special to access fields. Maybe try `thing.get('latitude')`

Comment: It looks like you need to call `thing.val()` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#foreach

Comment: thanks @RobbTraister this worked!